# ItextSharp PDF has no Header

Tags: c#, itext

I have created a console app that uses a memory stream to create a pdf file, to encrypt it and the add it as an attachment.

```
using (Stream output = new MemoryStream())
{
  Document document = new Document();
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    document.Open();
    var image = Image.GetInstance(renderedPayslip);
    image.ScaleToFit(600, 820);
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(2, 10);
    document.Add(image);

    using (var newTestStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      stream.CopyTo(newTestStream);
      newTestStream.Position = 0;

      document.Close();                               

      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream.ToArray());
      PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, newTestStream);     
      PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, newTestStream, true, "secret", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);

      reader.Close();
    }
//return sm.ToArray();
}
```

The problem is that it keeps on giving the message `PDF Header not found`.

Can some one help, please?

Comment: May be the file you streamed is currupts.

Comment: check can write file to local disk

Comment: @monasensiva what is the purpose of using an stamper in your codes ?

Comment: Stamper is wrapper cos on PdfEncryptor.Encrypt requires a stream and and file to encrypt but if you running from memory the stamper takes that physical files place.( from the info I read online )

Comment: `stream.CopyTo(...)` starts copying form the current read/write position of `stream`. I suspect, at this point in your code, the read/write position of `stream` is right **behind** the data the PdfWriter wrote to it (=end of stream, EOS). With `stream`'s read/write position being EOS,  `stream.CopyTo(...)` would be copying no data at all. Please debug your code thouroughly to verify your assumptions of how your code works and see what the content of all the MemoryStreams really is at each step of your program...

Comment: That said, i am not even sure if the PdfWriter has already written all pdf data to the MemoryStream before you initiate `stream.CopyTo(...)` (it could perhaps be that PdfWriter uses a lazy approach or internal buffering, i don't know...). Check the iText documentation whether you would need to explicitely instruct PdfWriter to flush or complete writing all data before you can use the stream. While you are at it, also check whether PdfWriter and PdfReader are `IDisposable`'s. If so, wrap them into `using` statements (similar to what you did with the MemoryStreams...)

Comment: What is that `stream.CopyTo(newTestStream)` good for anyways? You after all then reset the `newTestStream` position and thereafter use that memory stream as target of a `PdfStamper`... That being said, which line exactly *keeps on giving the message `PDF Header not found`*?

Comment: On the PDFReader. I added NewTestStream to try anything to get this process to work.  I will remove NewTestStream